# Gitignore update and updating index

Tags: git, gitignore

Per the instructions on [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files), I've added a global gitignore (including the config part) for Visual Studio/ASP.NET development. The remote and local repositories are already in place. How can I:

1) Update the index such that forthcoming updates only considers the new updates based on the global.
2) Remove items that were previously committed to the remote repository. Keeping them locally, however (believe I saw a guide online that would actually remove the local files as well).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you accidentally committed local project files (such as user preferences), and don't want to pull other users' local files to your copy.

1) you can't select which updates to pull from the remote. The `.gitignore` file is meant as a commit filter, not a fetch filter. However, you won't need this after you correctly execute step 2.

2) add the files you don't want to be in the remote repository to your `.gitignore`, then run `git rm filename`, commit and push the change. You may also want to commit your new `.gitignore` file, so that all other users get the same behavior.

Comment: Attempting to do that (wild card and individual files) and I receive a "fatal: pathspec 'directory/file' did not match any files" but if I ls directory, I see file. If I look at Gitlab, I see directory/file as well.

Comment: Perhaps you're not escaping the name correctly? You can also try a `git add`/`git commit` for the offending file, followed by `git rm`.